# Большое количество подключений script

Tags: javascript, html, css

Насколько мне известно, каждое подключение файлов css или js отбирает память у компьютера. А как много он отбирает? К примеру, нашел сайт в сети и на нем ~46 раз подключается script и 5 файлов css. Google speed page выдает 45% и меньше. Где можно почитать на эту тему?(не знаю как загууглить) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну хоть отдельно подключай, хоть все сразу, память будет тратиться одинаково при выполнении js скриптов (конечно если весь js нужен на данной странице).

Вот на скорость загрузки это влияет, так как файл может загрузиться одним запросом, либо будут отправляться несколько запросов на каждый файл и все это будет работать дольше, и как раз возможно браузер больше будет напрягаться, так как появятся доп запросы. Вот на всякий случай статья из хабра: https://habrahabr.ru/post/130276/

Вижу, что Битрикс, там в настройках главного модуля можно настроить объединение:

- Объединять CSS файлы;
- Объединять JS файлы;
- Подключать минифицированные версии CSS и JS файлов;
- Переместить весь Javascript в конец страницы;
- Создавать сжатую копию объединенных CSS и JS файлов;

Comment: еще вопрос. Ведь нет смысла подключать css и script в head, только если это не SPA? Ведь зачем подключать стили в начале, если страница не готова еще к работе.

Comment: @EpicLegend скрипты подключают в конце, просто потому что они блокируют дальнейшую загрузку страницы, пока не выполнятся. Если подключать их в head, пользователь будет наблюдать белый экран на всё время загрузки и выполнения скриптов. Если же они в конце body, то пользователь уже будет видеть какой-то текст на странице, если таковой имеется перед скриптами, пока эти самые скрипты грузятся